# Trust different Root Certificate Authorities in Chromium

Tags: linux, google-chrome, ssl, certificate, chromium

I'm using different Profiles with `--user-data-dir=` in Chromium under Linux. In one of the profiles I want to trust an additional root certificate authority (CA), that should not be trusted in the other profiles. According to the [documentation](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_cert_management.md) Chromium is using `$HOME/.pki/nssdb` for imported certificates. Is there any way I can use a different location for that trust store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't seem possible to change this location.

However, you could  set `$HOME` to a new location, create a new database and add your certificate there before running Chromium. For example, `$HOME` could be set to the same location as `--user-data-dir=`

It is worth noting that this approach starts Chromium out of your original home directory and makes certain configs unavailable to Chromium. At least I noticed that it would not use your desktop theme and downloads would go to a newly created home directory.

To illustrate, we can take a script from [here](https://blog.rabin.io/linux/start-chrome-temp-profile-with-preinstalled-extension), which runs Chromium in a temporary directory and modify it so that it imports Burp CA certificate before starting Chromium:

```
#!/bin/bash

BASE_TEMP_DIR=/tmp
CA_CERT=/opt/burp.der
TEMP_DIR=$(mktemp -d $BASE_TEMP_DIR/google-chome.XXXXXXX)

echo "Running Chrome with temp folder in: $TEMP_DIR"
export HOME=$TEMP_DIR
NSSDB=$HOME/.pki/nssdb/
mkdir -p $NSSDB
certutil -N -d sql:${NSSDB} --empty-password
certutil -d sql:${NSSDB} -A -t "C,," -n Burp -i $CA_CERT
google-chrome --user-data-dir=$TEMP_DIR --no-first-run --disable-reading-from-canvas --proxy-server="http://localhost:8080" "$@"

rm -rf $TEMP_DIR
```